# How to change container directory /var/www/html into other paths in wordpress project by docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I want to change container's directory /var/www/html into /var/www/vhosts/49/_cms/ but it does not work.
How can I change it?
Here is my docker-compose.yml file for wordpress project:

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mariadb:10.3.29
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "database"
       MYSQL_USER: "user"
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
       TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"

   wp49:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "49:80"
     volumes:
       - ./dist/_cms/wp-content:/var/www/vhosts/49/_cms/
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "user"
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wp49"
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the working directory in a compose file you need to add the `working_dir` directive

```
wp49:
 depends_on:
   - db
 image: wordpress:latest
 ports:
   - "49:80"
 volumes:
   - ./dist/_cms/wp-content:/var/www/vhosts/49/_cms/
 working_dir: /var/www/vhosts/49/_cms
 restart: always
 environment:
   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "user"
   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
   WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wp49"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I added working_dir, I got 403 error. Do you have any idea for this?